# LUKeychainAccessを使用した際のアプリケーション申請に関して

Tags: ios, iphone, github, apple, mit-license

iOSアプリケーション内からLUKeychainAccessを使ってキーチェーンに値を書き込み、アプリケーションが削除されてもキーチェーンを参照すればアプリのインストールが初めてか、そうではないかを判別するプログラムを考えています。

このアプリケーションにて、Appleの申請を行う際に、以下の質問事項があります。

Q1. アプリケーションのダウンロード履歴を残すために、キーチェーンを使用することはアプリケーション申請に問題はありませんでしょうか？

Q2. LUKeychainAccessはMITライセンスであるので、MITライセンスの規定通り、アプリケーション内にアプリケーションの説明として、MITライセンスの説明ページへのリンクを明示すればアプリケーション申請に問題はありませんでしょうか？（https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php）

Q3. Q2に関して、アプリケーション内ではなく、設定アプリケーションの中に、MITライセンスの説明ページへのリンクを明示すればアプリケーション申請に問題はありませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

> アプリケーションのダウンロード履歴を残すために、キーチェーンを使用することはアプリケーション申請に問題はありませんでしょうか？

厳密には本来のキーチェーンの使い方ではありませんが、そのようなアプリケーションが削除されても残る保存領域としての使い方は一般に広くなされていて、審査でそれが原因で拒否されたという話は聞いたことがありませんので、たいていは問題ありません。

> MITライセンスの説明ページへのリンクを明示すればアプリケーション申請に問題はありませんでしょうか？
>
> アプリケーション内ではなく、設定アプリケーションの中に、MITライセンスの説明ページへのリンクを明示すればアプリケーション申請に問題はありませんでしょうか？

OSSのライセンスはソフトウェアの作者との問題なので、どちらもアプリケーションの申請には関係ありません。別にライセンスの表示がなくてもアプリケーションはリリースできます。

一般的にはアプリケーションの内部、または設定アプリにてOSSライセンスの表示を行う方法は、どちらの方法も広く使われています。好きな方で表示するのが良いでしょう。

例えばアップル製のKeynoteやNumbersなどは設定アプリ内で「謝辞」としてOSSのライセンスを表示しています。InstagramやTwitterはアプリ内で表示しています。いくつかアプリを調べてみて、好みのやり方をマネするのが良いと思います。